# Create a number pyramid that decreases in value but each iteration goes up by odd numbers

Tags: java, loops

[image]

We we're tasked to create a number pyramid that decreases its value as as it goes down however each iteration repeats it by odd numbers. The output that I'm trying to aim is:

```
    5
   444
  33333
 2222222
111111111
```

But it doesn't print the complete pyramid, only those numbers from 5 to 3 get printed.

Here's the code that I used:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopExercise2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int rows = 5;
        
        // row counter; total rows will be decided by the scanned input
        for (int counter = 1; counter <= rows ; ++counter) {
            //System.out.print("7");
            // space counter before the number; creates the pyramid effect
            for (int space = 0; space <= rows ; ++space ) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            
            // per iteration, prints an odd number of values
            int n_counter = 0; // Initialize value to 0
            while (n_counter != 2 * counter - 1) {
                System.out.print(rows);
                ++n_counter;
            }
            // deducts 1 from the scanned input
            rows--;
            // prints a space to break the line
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add it, basically the output doesn't reach till the 1s...it only prints out 5 to 3 digits unlike what it should do

Comment: Have you learned about using the debugger in Eclipse? Now is a gret time to learn about it. Set a breakpoint on your loops and debug

Comment: I'm also new to Eclipse, but I'll try learning that thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rows = 5;
    for (int i = rows, j = 1; i > 0; --i, j += 2)
        System.out.println(" ".repeat(i) + Integer.toString(i).repeat(j));
}
```

output:

```
     5
    444
   33333
  2222222
 111111111
```

Comment: this is new to me, thank you for the answer I'll try understanding it now

Answer (score 1):

Your loop stop condition is changing each time. `counter <= rows` as you have `++counter` and `rows--`

Therefore, the loop stops at `initial rows value / 2`

I suggest you use a separate variable for the number that gets printed and decremented

Comment: but won't changing the variables change the entire output? because the rows also determine the number to be decreased by 1?

Comment: No? Adding a variable that's only used to print doesn't change the fact that your loop goes from `counter = 1; counter <= 5`.. I'm saying that your problem is that you're currently modifying the 5 to make it smaller, meanwhile the counter gets bigger. You should remove `row--` and let the loop actually go to 5 but you need a different variable to print at each row